# 97 f150 4.6L Heater problem!

Tags: ford, overheating, f-150

In August, I replaced my heater core after a few yrs of it being out. Engine would get to normal operating temp and heater would blow warm/hot. Then slowly, the temp gauge would drop to cold, heater would blow cold. Temp gauge to normal, blow cold. Them temp gauge would peg at over heat.(over temp light). Replaced t-stat. Same! Replaced radiator cap, same! Took it to a dealership, couldn't find the problem(no cost). When it starts to over heat, I pull over and turn the truck off, and restart a few times, then it seams to work fine. Normal running temp, heater works great! Thought since I bought cheaper t-stat maybe change it again. Same! Any thoughts?